# How to get a rating bar for showing progress of Quiz Game in android sdk

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing Android Quiz game using ADT eclipse , here i want to show the rating bar for showing progress. Any help and suggestion will be most valuable for me.

Comment: progress bar have max number in it. set it like 10, now if your are on question 1 then progressBar.setProgress(1)..progressBar.setProgress(2)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for Ratting bar , check it out

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    //get rating bar object
    RatingBar bar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);   
    bar.setNumStars(5);
    bar.setStepSize(0.5f);
    //get text view
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);   
    //get score
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score= b.getInt("score");
    //display score
    bar.setRating(score);
    switch (score)
    {
    case 1:t.setText("Your text here");
    break;
    case 2: t.setText("Your text here");
    break;
    case 3:t.setText("Your text here");
    break;
    case 4:t.setText("Your text here");
    break;
    case 5:t.setText("Your text here");
    break;
    }
}
```